# How to prompt mobile user in flutter web-app to install native app

Tags: flutter

I've built my flutter app for web/ios/android. The web version is hosted on firebase if that matters. When I open the web version in a mobile browser there are two possible experiences:

1. If the user has the native app installed the browser displays a nice banner prompting them to open the native app.
2. If the user does not have the native app installed, no banner.

Is there a simple way in the second scenario to have the browser display a banner prompting the user to install the native app and a link to the relevant store?

Thanks!

Comment: This is the behaviour of web apps you can install them in devices but still they work on a web view i.e. they just creating a shortcut of your webapp, and Yes it'll be different from native app. I think there's no way to display a different banner as this banner is showing by the browser.

Comment: @Aks thanks, I edited the question to try and make it clearer.